# tinymce popup not working in Adobe flex air app

Tags: apache-flex, tinymce, adobe

I downloaded this flex air app from  http://coderscollective.com/code_samples.aspx?page_id=620.
the tinymce richTextEditor does show up in the swif .
however when clicking on all tinymce popups nothing happens . any idea !

Comment: can you provide a live example?

Comment: theres a source file that you cas download in the link above . I tested it with tinymce 3.2.1.1 and i have that issue .

Comment: i recommend using the latest tinymce version

Answer (score 1):

Just in case : it seems that this happens due to security sand box restrictions that air runtime impose.

this link explain some techniques to avoid those : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f0e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ef8 .

exememple (in the table plugin i have to modifie the validate listner as below :
        document.getElementById("insert").addEventListener("click", function() { insertTable();return
false; });